# Change SSL access port on Azure Managed Cache?

Tags: azure

Is there any way to change the SSL access port from 6380 for MS Azure Redis Cache?

The following page refers to changing ports but I can't find it in the latest portal.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn793612.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#AccessPorts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the port. For Redis Cache there have been some changes in the Portal UI. You can access the port settings using the Settings tab. I am including a screenshot from the portal which shows you the access ports [image]

Comment: these settings (ports) are read-only - it seems like there is no way to change them.

Comment: The SSL port number is fixed to 6380. What is your scenario where you have to change that?

Comment: There are a few reasons on why you would need to change the default port settings, notably because of corporate firewall restrictions. Besides, to stay on topic, the OP asks "is there any way to change the SSL access port from 6380 for MS Azure Redis Cache?". And it seems like it is impossible, that's what I wanted to point out. Maybe you should update your answer.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please open a suggestion http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169382-cache so we can track it. Updating my answer as well.

Comment: Ports still cannot be changed in April 2022, here is the new link to the feature request for ability to change ports (vote for it!):
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/96d3e7ff-0c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8